# Getting the ID argument in a function as a range in R

Tags: r, range, data-science

I am trying to undertake a Data Science Course online and I am extremely new to R Programming. I am tasked to create a function that takes in three arguments, directory,pollutant and id and it should return the mean of the pollutant specified over the range of the ids required. The following is the code I am stuck at

```
pollutantmean2 <- function(directory, pollutant, id){
  library(dplyr)
  a = "(Whatever Directory the files are located in)"
  b = directory
  wd = paste(a,b, sep = "/")
  setwd(wd)
  files = list.files()
  csv = lapply(files,read.csv)
  df = do.call(rbind,csv)

  na_vec = which(!complete.cases(df))
  valid_data = df[-na_vec, ]
  id = group_by(valid_data,ID)

  values = 0

  mean_value = summarise(id,mean_sulfate = mean(sulfate),mean_nitrate = mean(nitrate))
}
```

I thought about creating a dataframe that contains the mean values and using the range, getting the sum of the mean. However, I am at a loss as to how do I go about making the id as a range. I figured out that one way I can do it is to create a vector of say x = c(1,2) but that requires me to manually select. The desired output is as [this example](https://d3c33hcgiwev3.cloudfront.net/_3b0da118473bfa0845efddcbe29cc336_pollutantmean-demo.html?Expires=1581292800&Signature=cnpTQUxGQyAD6Ns8A20jULeZIC892OTNiZRbQdPVrRhw-bhjk0-7Xjnx9~cElqMp~MtBt97x-XOLCX~vXAhfskTTEuYtW5UCax1oZMuX3bGjJqsqfEa1DexKUnadDUnhNYsZ8~kjgLk-UlQKlZpzlqjEKUN9CNsRiIOhWuQjCZc_&Key-Pair-Id=APKAJLTNE6QMUY6HBC5A)

Comment: Replace the last 3 code lines by `valid_data %>%
group_by(valid_data,ID) %>%
summarise(mean_sulfate = mean(sulfate),mean_nitrate = mean(nitrate))
`.

Comment: There are many questions on SO dealing with this data and this question. Many of the answers there address issues you have here and/or questions you have yet to ask. I searched for [`[r] directory pollutant id`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Br%5D+directory+pollutant+id) (strangely specific, I know) and found many relevant questions, often with multiple answers each.